# spring boot application with data JPA added data many time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-devtools

I created Spring Boot application with data JPA and add Dev Tool dependency and created one simple
login page in JSP and and Registration page . when I fill register form and register data is fetch in controller using @ModelAttribute and save this data to Data Base and  go back to login page and refresh login page  2 or 3 times then my data save 2,3 times in data base.
[User Entity Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERfVs.png)

[Login JSP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFYoI.png)

[Registration JSP page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgRDU.png)

[Controller Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEQqe.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you are directly returning a view after a post request, when you should be redirecting. Returning a redirect response to the page you need after succesful registration should fix your problem. The easiest way to do it in spring in your case should be returning - "redirect:/your-redirect-url".

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083357/do-you-always-redirect-after-post-if-yes-how-do-you-manage-it) should be useful as well.

Also this - [how to redirect](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward).